# List all indexed ids in Google Cloud Vector Search (prev. Matching Engine) Index

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using Google Cloud Vector Search to store image embeddings. I am interested in finding the best matches within a list of images that changes over time, so I need to insert new images and delete old ones on a weekly basis.

I am able to perform the operations above, using [batch updates](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/update-rebuild-index) but there is no way for me to check if the content of the vector index is actually correct. All I can get is the total number of image ids in the index.

Is there any way for a developer to inspect the contents of a vector index on Google Cloud? I want some API that could return all the image ids in the index.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same question still

Comment: Unfortunately not. For now I am just calling the batch update method and hoping it works. I was not able to find a way to check the contents of the vector index.